# ubuntu flash boot offering only erase all data and install instead of 50/50 with macos

Tags: 22.04

got a macbook early 2016, but i wanted ubuntu as well. I want both. I Downloaded 22.04, booted it up, got to installation. It offered only erase all or something else options then went onto another screen and a load of file options dev/etc. Any ideas why it doesn’t offer me the partitioned alternative?

Comment: Maybe the installer cannot read/understand the existing Mac partitions/file systems.  Best to use native tools to shrink/move partitions to make free space for the installer to use.

Comment: I used boot camp and it said there is no space on the disk. Says there is 1gb to be precise. SSD is 251gb and I use about 130gb….